# I sent my Humaniq & Taas coin (from my ico purchase) to my Parity Wallet.

Tags: synchronization, tokens, recovery, parity-wallet

Being a newb to crypto I screwed up. I sent the taas and humaniq coins I bought during their ico to my Parity wallet. Nothing has appeared and I now think that maybe this wallet only supports ethereum? Are my coins lost forever or can I recover somehow?

Comment: By parity wallet do you then mean an account that you have in your parity wallet? If so, this account should now hold the tokens you're talking about. Can you provide your account address? Then we can check.

Comment: Are you fully synchronized? Parity supports tokens very well.

Answer (score 2):

although I am not totally familiar with TaaS, humaniq and parity, all you need to do is to be able to sign transactions with the account that now owns the tokens.

1. There must be a way of exporting key files with parity, I assume they are stored in a data dir somewhere.
2. Import the key file to MetaMask, a plugin for Chrome to connect to the Ethereum network and do/sign transactions through the browser.
3. If there is a web interface for transfering these tokens, just open it, and - with metamask initalized by klicking the fox icon - you can now transfer your tokens wherever you want to, because to TaaS and humaniq, you are identified as the owner of the tokens now.

Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

Have you set a watch on the token contract within Parity? Due to the way tokens work on the Ethereum network, they don't show up in your wallet by default, you have to add them as a currency to watch.

To watch a token balance:

1. If you don't have a contracts tab, go to settings and enable it
2. Go to the contracts tab and click "watch contract"
3. Enter the contract address of the token you want to watch (Humaniq, then repeat steps 2-3 with Taas).